# Sqoop command to drop a table in RDBMS

Tags: hadoop, sqoop

Hi I'm new to Hadoop and sqoop. Can some one tell me command to sqoop drop a table from rdbms.

Answer (score 0):

Sqoop should not be used to drop a table.

You can try this, but I doubt it'll work. `sqoop eval --query 'DROP TABLE ...'`

Ref: [`sqoop eval`](http://sqoop.apache.org/docs/1.4.7/SqoopUserGuide.html#_purpose_11)